#  Unable to serialize an object

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

Below is the code that I am using to serialize an object

```
College college = new College();
college= (College)(Session["XML"]);

public void serializetoxml(College college)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer myserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(college.GetType());
    // XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(College));
    TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\invoice.xml");
    myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, college);
    mywriter.Close();
}
```

Sorry , I missed to paste the code for my class, here it is

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="")]           [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute]
public partial class College{

    /// <remarks/>
    public Header header;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Student")]
    public Student Student;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Summary summary;
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true,Namespace="")] 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute]
public partial class Invoice {


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Activity")]

    public List<Activity> Activity;

        }
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Activity{

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string StudentNumber;


    /// <remarks/>        
    public string mark1;

    ///  <remarks/> typed it in manually

    public string mark2;
   }
```

This is the error that I am getting {"There was an error reflecting type 'A.Common.College'."}

It is an example of realtimeclass.

Comment: What is the question?  Your title says unable to serialize.. What is your error?

Comment: Can you provide some details on  "unable to serialize" ? Also it would help if you can post the code for the class `College`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is your code. What's the issue? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Is the file `c:\invoice.xml` in use?

Comment: @Janet: learn to include the **complete** exception. Catch the exception, display the result of ex.ToString(), then post that here. Then, get rid of the try/catch you added.

Comment: There is nothing about the College class as you posted it that makes it not serializable (I just tested it and works fine using stubs for Header, Summary, and Student). Please post the contents of Header, Summary, and Student classes, the problem is likely in one of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the inner exception that you are getting. It will tell you which field/property it is having trouble serializing.

You can exclude fields/properties from xml serialization by decorating them with the [XmlIgnore()] attribute.